# .push() command in javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to push a url into an array then window.open() all urls in the array, I get a null error. I believe this is because the url is not being properly placed in the array to start. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Series Name:
        <input type="text"
            name="series1name"
            id="seriesname"/>
        <br/>
        Series Link:
        <input type="text"
            name="series1link"
            id="serieslink"/>
    </form>
    <div>
        <button onclick="AddSeries()">Add A New Series </button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button onclick="OpenSeries()">Open Incomplete Series </button>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var urlArray = [];

    function AddSeries() {

        var url = document.getElementById('serieslink');    
        urlArray.push(url);
    }

    function OpenSeries() {
        for (url in urlArray) {
       alert(url.constructor === Array);
           window.open(url, '_blank');
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

I'm sorry if the error is obvious, I am somewhat new to coding and so I'm sure this code isn't perfect by any means.
Thank you in advance.

Thank you everyone, a combination of two responses got my code to work the way I wanted it to.

Comment: [Don't use for..in to iterate over arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: You cannot have HTML code between `</body>` and `</html>`. Move your `<script>` _before_ `</body>`. Also, please learn to debug such simple coding mistakes yourself by [using the console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525).

Comment: @Juhana While this may be another issue, it is not what is preventing push() from putting the url into the array.

Comment: @Xufox the location of my close body tag makes no difference on the workings of the program

Comment: It’s still invalid HTML.

Comment: @Xufox You are correct, thank you for pointing that out, but I would prefer if you worked towards solving my question.

Comment: @user6762872 Why? Your question has already been answered.

Comment: That's why it was a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Get the value of the textbox, not the textbox

You need to add the value of the textbox, not the textbox itself

```
var url = document.getElementById('serieslink').value;
```

When you run `document.getElementById()`, the return value is an object with many properties and methods.  You can [read about Element objects here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

### Use the proper for loop

Pointed out by @Juhana

The `for in` loop will give you the key of an associative array or object.  If the array is non-associative (which all arrays are in JavaScript), the use the `for of` loop instead.  [You can read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

### Put script tag in the Body

Pointed out by @Xufox

`<script>` tags **should** be inside of the `<body>` tag.  And putting the script at the end of the body is recommended to decrease load time.